# How to loop a process in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, select-by-attribute, iterator

I'm trying to count how many star points there are in 500 meters radius around each property in the month of its transaction. I created buffers around each property transaction firstly.

Since each transaction happened in different months, and there are different distribution of star points in different months, I use **Select By Attributes Tool** and for example, input `"month"=1` for property buffer and `"month"=1` for star points respectively, and then I use spatial join tool to get join counts. (Please tell me if this process is wrong)

However, I need to repeat this process for about 10 years, so I'm wondering to know is it possible to let ModelBuilder do it automatically?

I have tried to use **Batch** for twice, but unfortunately, my computer showed not responding.

---

I am trying to learn to use  **iterators**, and i found that every model can only have one iterator. Since I need to change two expressions of **select** for two input features, I'm wondering to know is it possible to do it using only one iterator?

(I suppose I am still not quiet familiar with how iterators work, but I'm trying to learning it.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you actually need two iterators, you can create a model with an iterator and a collect values tool.  You can then add that model as a tool in your current model (which can also contain an iterator).  However, it is likely that your tables are related somehow and you can do a join prior to the iteration.

Comment: If the value is the same in both tables, you just need to iterate field values on one feature class and use the values for the select on both layers.  You would have two select tools, but you connect the 'value' output from the iterator to both select tools as the expression.

Answer (score 4):

ModelBuilder has the ability to [**iterate**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/a-quick-tour-of-using-iterators-for-iteration-looping-.htm) different things. So, provided your table has a field with all the values you need, you could [**iterate over that field**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-field-value.htm) to get all the unique values. Alternatively, if you have a list of values, you could [**iterate Multivalue**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-multivalue.htm).

Comment: Here is help docs on this: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/examples-of-using-iterators-in-modelbuilder.htm